# Error when trying to fetch from wikipedia

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch from the wikipedia api and I get the "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" error. I do not know if it has to do with the way I am appending params. I have no experience with that and I just googled a solution. I tested the parameters on postman so I know it's the right data.

```
      const searchQuery = async () => {
        const params = {
          action: "query",
          format: "json",
          list: "search",
          srsearch: "salvador dali",
        };
    
        const url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/");
    
        for (let param in params) {
          url.searchParams.append(param, params[param]);
        }
        
        const searchData = await fetch(url);
        console.log(searchData);
        const data = await searchData.json();
        console.log(data);
      };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. To get around this, make the request from the server side or use a service like [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).

```js
const url = new URL("https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/");
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use cors anywhere. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Hilary Just use the URL https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/

Comment: I used it as a url and I got an error saying the url is not valid

Comment: @Hilary I cannot reproduce that. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bLzqjc9t/